# how to display category names in prestashop's custom page?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

I want to get category names as select box  in my custom module file discount.php which creates display in backoffice. I am calling the function `$cat = CategoryCore::getCategories();` from `category.php` now when I `var_dump($cat);` I am getting array but I am not sure how will I get the names only.

Is there any other way to get category names?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$categories = Category::getCategories($this->context->language->id);

foreach ($categories as $category)
    echo $category['name'];
```